# Can RestKit (the Python package) be used with Tornado in a non-blocking manner?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

We're working on a resource-oriented architecture using Tornado, and would love not to have to roll our own REST consumer.

[RestKit](http://benoitc.github.io/restkit/) (the Python package, not the iOS library) looks like a really great option, but it's not clear whether its I/O is blocking.  It does have built-in Gevent support, but my understanding is that Tornado doesn't play well with Gevent, so that's not really a solution.

Is there a way to adapt something like this to work well with Tornado?  If so, how would one go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it uses return, it blocks. So this:

```
r = request("http://google.com")
```

blocks the Tornado IOLoop.

I don't think you can use gevent with Tornado. It may be possible to use eventlet, but I think a thread pool is simpler if you really want to use a blocking library.

```
from futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.gen import coroutine
from tornado.concurrent import run_on_executor
from restkit import request


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(6)

    @run_on_executor
    def async_request(self, *args, **kwds):
        return request(*args, **kwds)

    @coroutine
    def get(self):
        urls = ["http://yahoo.fr",
                "http://google.com",
                "http://friendpaste.com",
                "http://benoitc.io",
                "http://couchdb.apache.org"]

        for url in urls:
            resp = yield self.async_request(url, follow_redirect=True)
            self.write("RESULT: %s: %s (%s)\n" % (url, resp.status, len(resp.body_string())))

        self.finish()

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

This uses [futures](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/concurrent.futures.html) (which has been backported) and [tornado.gen](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html).

I've found it's simpler to just build HTTPRequest objects and use the Tornado [httpclient](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html), though. Threads (or gevent, or whatever) add additional complexity to your app.

Comment: Yeah, the Tornado AsyncHTTPClient is awesome, but a lot of utility libraries that provide a ton of additional functionality beyond simple HTTP requests depend on the requests library these days.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might be a solution: this [trequests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trequests/0.9.3) package looks like it can monkey-patch any requests-dependent module to execute requests in a non-blocking manner.